# Divisors of at least one of three numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Question: Find the number of positive integers that are divisors of at least one of $10^{10}$, $15^7$, $18^{11}$.

My solution (my answer was wrong): I thought that the numbers that are divisors of at least one of these three numbers would be all of the numbers that are divisors of their LCM.

I proceeded to find the LCM using the prime factorizations:
$$10^{10}=2^{10}\cdot 5^{10}$$
$$15^7=3^7\cdot 5^7$$
$$18^{11}=2^{11}\cdot 3^{11}\cdot 3^{11}=2^{11}\cdot 3^{22}$$
From here, I saw that the LCM is $2^{11}\cdot 3^{22}\cdot 5^{10}$.

This would imply that the number of positive integer divisors is $(11+1)(22+1)(10+1)=(12)(23)(11)=3036$, which is wrong.

I don't see any glaring mistakes with my arithmetic, so that would mean that my initial reasoning is incorrect. Where am I going wrong and what am I missing here?

Sorry for the excessively simplistic question, but help would be greatly appreciated here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong to assume that any number that divides the LCM must also divide one of the individual numbers. The LCM itself divides the LCM without dividing any of these numbers.

You can find the answer by using the inclusion-exclusion principle. By that method the answer = 11 * 11 + 8 * 8 + 12 * 23 - 8 - 8 - 11 + 1 = 121 + 64 + 276 - 26 = 435. Is this correct?

Comment: Thank you! The Principle Inclusion-Exclusion is a much better way to go on this problem. And yes, 435 would be correct.

Comment: What!? Are you sure 435 is correct? $18^{11}$ has only 276 divisors. It shares 11 of those divisors with $10^{10}$ and 8 of those divisors with $15^7$.

Comment: Robert yes, and similarly the other numbers also have other factors they don't share with $18^11$